# Take 'Backup' of SQL Server Compact database

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-ce

Is it possible to take Backup of SQL Server Compact database (i.e. *.sdf) and Restore the same.

Comment: SQL Server Compact is not SQL SERVER. Is a subset of SQL. If you want full SQL Server compatiblity use SQL Server Express.

Answer (score 10):

Just copy the file.  Done.

Quote from [Maintaining Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172411.aspx):

> Because SQL Server Compact 3.5 is a
>   file-based database system, you can
>   accomplish many common database tasks
>   such as backing up, restoring, and
>   deleting a database by using the file
>   system APIs.
>
> To back up a database, close all
>   connections to the database, and then
>   copy the .sdf file. To restore a
>   database, copy the .sdf file back to
>   its regular working location. These
>   operations work even if the database
>   is set up for replication. To drop a
>   database, delete the .sdf database
>   file.

Comment: No programmatically we need to take backup like,

SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(); 
cmd.Connection = conn; cmd.CommandText = @"BACKUP DATABASE [D:\\CompactDatabases\\Northwind.sdf] TO DISK = 'C:\\Test\\DB.bak'"; cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

int i=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

but it is throwing exception as below : 

There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = BACKUP ] Then how take the backup programmatically?

Comment: Programmatically?  Sure.  File.Copy("mydb.sdf", mybackup.sdf");

Comment: The biggest issue with the file based restore you mentioned AngryHacker is "close all connections to the database"

This may not be possible without taking the website offline (assuming it's a website) and even then the application pool process may be holding the file open.

Answer (score 2):

I write the compact SQL database out to an XML file using LINQ to SQL and read it back in to restore it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Do you think we can restore backup taken from SQL Server database in to SQL Server Compact database.