# Data Backup & Restore of SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 Edition?

Tags: c#, sql, desktop, sql-server-ce-3.5

Is data backup and restore functionality possible in SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 edition ?

I have developed and installed a C# desktop application which is working perfectly. My app can store and manipulate data.

Now I want to backup that data stored in the SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 which is embedded to my application. I also want to produce reports from the data already stored.

Can anyone say:

IS IT POSSIBLE OR NOT ? IF POSSIBLE CAN YOU , PLEASE, GIVE ME A LINK OF WALK THROUGH TO DO THAT.

Thank You

Comment: Yes - sure - just copy the `.sdf` file to some other place ... SQL Server Compact has all its data and metadata stored inside this single `.sdf` file - just copy it - that's your backup

Comment: Please don't use caps, try to use the markup tags instead to draw attention to a certain sentence or make your post more readable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Take 'Backup' of SQL Server Compact database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294656/take-backup-of-sql-server-compact-database)

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN, you just copy the file to make a backup, and same for a restore. You can [view the documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172411%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). It's at the very bottom of the page.

The code is really easy:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFileName, destFileName);
```

[Here's another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294656/take-backup-of-sql-server-compact-database) about this topic which will tell you that you have to not be using the .sdf file when you backup / copy else it'll be locked.

Good Luck!

Comment: Problem Solved...

Thank You all for Your Help.